# Trigger to record timestamp on inserted row - how to convert this to stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, powerapps

Using Microsoft SQL Server 14.

I have a trigger on a table to record a timestamp to whatever row gets inserted. The data will be inserted from a PowerApp.

The problem is, I discovered PowerApps cannot write to a table if it has a trigger.

My trigger is below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_ModTimestamp] 
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    -- add timestamp to Modified_Timestamp column
    SET [Modified_Timestamp] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    -- to the rows that were inserted
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM inserted)
END
GO
```

I've read that to get around this PowerApps limitation, I can write a stored procedure instead.

Can this be done in a stored procedure? Because I also read that stored procedures don't have access to the `inserted` table... the more I research this the more impossible it seems.

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: So do you get an error when you try to perform the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` when Powerapps tries to use the table?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Inserted/deleted-tables are defined only in the triggers. But I am a little bit confused:  if you can use stored procedure to insert records to the table what prevents you from setting [Modified_TimeStamp] inside the procedure?

Comment: As for using a stored procedure, this means you move the `UPDATE`/`INSERT` to that procedure and so *it* would define the value for `Modified_Timestamp` in said `INSERT`/`UPDATE`; you don't need the `inserted` object at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL Server 14" ?? Using SQL Server **2014** (which is internally v12) - or are you using SQL Server 2017 (which is **v14.xx**) ? Please be more specific

Comment: @Kendle so when somebody updates a row, will that default value update to the time of the edit?

Comment: @Larnu I have not got an error yet. I am trying to plan ahead. Any row that the power app edits, i'd like the time stamp of that edit. I could just use the powerApp to send the current date and time while editing the row.